# Define folder depth for the verbose option in Copy-Item cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following command to copy a directory tree from one folder to another.

```
Copy-Item $SOURCE $DEST -Filter {PSIsContainer} -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

The verbose option is correctly showing each folder that is copied. However, I would like to tell the Verbose option to only shows the first level of the subfolders that are copied. Hence the subfolders/subfolders/... etc wouldn't appear.

Is it possible?

Comment: So to confirm, you want to perform a fully recursive copy but only _report_ the first level of subfolders?

Comment: Good point. If this is accurate, the answer I gave would require an Else statement  that loses the Recurse.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to achieve. If this is not possible, I'll just report every folder. But because the number of folder is over 100k, I'm trying to decrease the report information. I would probably want to do the same thing with robocopy and a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `-Verbose` option, you could use the `-PassThru` option to process the successfully processed items via the pipeline. In the following example, I am assuming that `$DEST` is the *existing* directory in which the newly copied directory will appear. (You cannot call `Get-Item` on non-existant objects.)

```
$SOURCE = Get-Item "foo"
$DEST   = Get-Item "bar"

Copy-Item $SOURCE $DEST -Filter {PSIsContainer} -Recurse -Force -PassThru | Where-Object {

  # Get the parent object.  The required member is different between
  # files and directories, which makes this a bit more complex than it
  # might have been.

  if ($_.GetType().Name -eq "DirectoryInfo") {
    $directory = $_.Parent
  } else {
    $directory = $_.Directory
  }

  # Select objects as required, in this case only allow through
  # objects where the second level parent is the pre-existing target
  # directory.

  $directory.Parent.FullName -eq $DEST.FullName
}
```

Comment: When I run this, I receive the following message:
`cmdlet Where-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
FilterScript:`.

Comment: That's peculiar.  I thought that syntax was the most universal as it goes back to PowerShell v2. It's as if the `Where-Object` cmdlet didn't have a script block. Did you try the code above as-is?

Comment: Yes, with the exception that I replaced $SOURCE and $DEST with hard coded path (i.e. `"C:\aaa"` and `"C:\bbb"`). I'll give it another try.

Comment: The `$DEST` on the second to last line needs to be the object returned by `Get-Item` since it accesses the `FullName` property. I did it that way to avoid manual path manipulation.

Comment: I was able to make it works, however, the code also copies files. I just want the directories. I added the `-Filter {PSIsContainer}` to the `Copy-Item` options in your code.

Comment: OK. I added that part of the original code to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of backslashes in the path and add logic to select first level only perhaps.  Something like this perhaps?

```
$Dirs=get-childitem $Source -Recurse | ?{$_.PSIsContainer}
Foreach ($Dir in $Dirs){
    $Level=([regex]::Match($Dir.FullName,"'b")).count
    if ($Level -eq 1){Copy-Item $Dir $DEST -Force -Verbose}
    else{Copy-Item $Dir $DEST -Force}}
```

*Edited to include looping and logic per requirements

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `else if` statement with the same `Copy-Item` call but this time without the `-Verbose` option?

Comment: Indeed.  I didn't realize that requirement when I first read your question.

Comment: I'm trying to make your code work, as it is not working on my computer. `$SOURCE` and `$DEST` are hard coded path (i.e. `$SOURCE = "C:\aaa"` and `$DEST = "C:\bbb"`). So I'm not sure that `$Source.FullName` is needed in your solution.

Comment: It seems to never go in the `if` statement, so something is probably wrong with `$Level`.

Comment: You are correct.  The $Source.fullname should be $Dir.fullname.  That didn't get changed when I put it in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `robocopy` instead of `copy-item`. Its `/LEV:n` switch sounds like it's exactly what you're looking for. Example (you'll need to test & tweak to meet your requirements):

```
robocopy $source $dest /LEV:2
```

`robocopy` has approximately 7 gazillion options you can specify to get some very useful and interesting behavior out of it.

Comment: I'm not using robocopy. So I'm looking for a solution that works with the Copy-Item cmdlet. Also, the `/LEV:n` option of robocopy is not for what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Why don't you want to use robocopy? Use the right tool for the job - and in this case, I think robocopy *is* better suited to the task.

Comment: I'm using `Copy-Item` cmdlet because, when measured with `Measure-Command`, it was faster for copying directory tree when compared to the robocopy solution.